# IdentityServer3 Guidance Needed

Tags: identityserver3

I have a scenario where a client has an OpenIdConnect (OIDC) token in their possession.  The OIDC was issued from an external OIDC provider, I am not the OIDC provider, just the downstream consumer of it.

The goal is for the client to exchange said OIDC Token, for temporary credentials, or an accesstoken, which will then give them api access to more specific resources.

In my case, the OIDC represents a user.  The client, has a ClientId/Secret, which is used to establish service-2-service trust.  In the end I would like to have something that looks a lot like the CustomGrant token Request.

```
static TokenResponse GetCustomGrantToken()
{
        var client = new TokenClient(
           token_endpoint,
           "custom_grant_client",
           "cd19ac6f-3bfa-4577-9579-da32fd15788a");

        var customParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "some_custom_parameter", "some_value" }
        };

        var result = client.RequestCustomGrantAsync("custom", "read", customParams).Result;
        return result;
}
```

where my customParams would contain the OIDC to my user.

Problem: I can get a token back from the GetCustomGrantToken call, however a follow up Webapi call fails to pass Authorization.  i.e. Identity.isAuthenticated is false.

The it all works fine if I get a clientcredential token.

```
static TokenResponse GetClientToken()
    {
        var client = new TokenClient(
            token_endpoint,
            "silicon",
            "F621F470-9731-4A25-80EF-67A6F7C5F4B8");

        return client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api1").Result;
    }
```

Had the CustomGrantToken worked I would have put my users account info in the claims, thus giving me context in the subsequent WebApi calls.

Any direction would be appreciated.